# Xcode iPhone SDK - Show gif image on app Launch

Tags: xcode, ios5, gif

I currently have a mp4 video converted from a gif playing at app launch, but using a video stops playing music and has problems with airplay devices connected.

Anyways what i really want is showing my gif on app launch. But i can't seem to get the gif to "play" it only shows one frame, how do i make it play the whole gif ?

My current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// Show Animation;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Launch" ofType:@"mp4"]];
LaunchPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];
LaunchPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
LaunchPlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
LaunchPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
LaunchPlayer.view.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubview:LaunchPlayer.view];
[LaunchPlayer.moviePlayer play];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(LaunchFinish) 
                                             name:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification"
                                           object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't see how the code you posted has anything to do with using a .gif, you its sticking to the first frame because iOS will not run an animated .gif. However, you can export each frame of your animation as a separate image and animate them like this.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame1.gif"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame2.gif"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame3.gif"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame4.gif"], nil];


    imageView.animationDuration = 2.0; 
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; 
    [imageView startAnimating]; 

}
```

Comment: @Aleksander Well you can't just play it, however you can use photoshop or a number of other programs to break it down to individual frames.

Answer (score 5):

In my little example here. i used a UIWEBVIEW called webView and had spinning-loader.gif added as a resource. The image can me put anywhere in the project as long as its added. This showed the gif as well as made it animate. Hope this helps.

```
NSString *pathImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"spinning-loader" ofType:@"gif"];
NSString* webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"<html><body><img style='width:85;height:85;' src=\"file://%@\" /></body></html>", pathImg];
[webView loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];

webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.opaque=FALSE;
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```